# No module named 'airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_speech_to_text_operator'

Tags: cloud, speech-to-text, google-cloud-composer

I am not able to import statement as

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_speech_to_text_operator import GcpSpeechToTextRecognizeSpeechOperator
```

I get the error 
No module named 'airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_speech_to_text_operator'

I am using airflow version 1.10.2 and the composer version is 1.7.2

Answer (score 1):

The `gcp_speech_to_text_operator` operator is not present in 1.10.2 and neither in 1.10.3. You will be able to find it from [1.10.4](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4rc1/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_speech_to_text_operator.py).

If you really need it you could copy the code and make a [plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) and put the code into the plugin directory in the composer instance bucket.
You can use my [custom plugin](https://github.com/huq-industries/airflow-plugins) as an example of how to do it. Bear in mind that you need to be sure that your airflow version is compatible.

Comment: Your 1.10.4 link is broken.